# beeline got stuck when connect to jdbc on spark thrift server

Tags: apache-spark, beeline

Today morning one server is down, and the beeline do not work after server restart.

there were many beeline processes stuck on the server when exec jps...

I restart the server, but do not help... It works on other server, so I think there is something wrong with current server.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.